# Pipewire using 2x processes when idling

Tags: optimization, pipewire

I recently had my BT headphones stutter and cut out and realized that during CPU intensive processing, pipewire is dropping frames. My overall goal, then, is to streamline processing to make that situation happen rarely or never.

With that in mind, I noticed today that pipewire has quite a bit of processing going on, even while no audio is occurring:

[image: htop showing pipewire processes]

Combined, these processes are taking over 10% of one CPU.

My question is twofold:

1. Is it normal to have 2 of each process running for pipewire (pipewire, pipewire-pulse, and pipewire-gnome-session)? If not, how can I reduce this to 1 each?
2. Why are these processes even taking any CPU when there is no system audio streaming anywhere? Is there a way to reduce CPU usage while idling?